# How do I get the Strobulb?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

I realize that the strobulb is on the chandelier, and I can get the chandelier to go down by sucking on the ceiling fan, so then I run down and try to suck the strobulb off the chandelier from the bottom floor when it is lowered...and nothing seems to work. Am I just not sucking properly? How do I get the strobulb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you do the following:

- Drop the chandelier ALL the way down. Suck up the fan until it stops moving.
- Run downstairs immediately after you stop turning the fan. Actually run, with <kbd>B</kbd>. Walking is just a bit too slow.
- Press <kbd>X</kbd> to pick up the bulb. Just walk up to it and you'll get a prompt, you do NOT suck the bulb up with the Poltergust. You'll have to be on the same side of the chandelier as the bulb to get it.

Comment: Oh, okay, I was trying to suck it up, and that is where the problem was. Apparently sucking does not solve everything.